# Getting conversion failed error even when CONVERT function is not being called SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I use this command to select all the specific dates if the given variable is date, if it is not it should return all of the fields.

The commands works when `@query` is in the form of a date, but it returns an error:

*"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."*

when it is any other arbitrary string.

Code:

```
select * from table where

format(dateofbirth,'dd/MMM/yyyy') = Case 
    when ISDATE(@query)=1 then 
        format(CONVERT(datetime,@query),'dd/MMM/yyyy')  
    else
        format(dateofbirth,'dd/MMM/yyyy')
```

**Edit:**

`@query` can be any string for eg. "1/1/2013" , "random" , "3".

The command should return all fields if `@query` is not in form of a date.

Comment: You might want to specify what DBMS you are using...

Comment: You are converting `@query` to datetime, when it is already a datetime.

Comment: `@query` is not always datetime, it can be anything
. it works fine if i pass a date in form of string but gives me the error when i pass anything else to `@query`. 
I want it to return all fileds if i pass anything which is not in form of a date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around this problem by re-formulating your query condition like this:

```
declare @query as varchar(20)='blah'
SELECT *
FROM testtable
WHERE ISDATE(@query) = 0
   OR CONVERT(date, dateofbirth) = CASE ISDATE(@query)
       WHEN 1 THEN CONVERT(date, @query) ELSE NULL
   END
```

[Demo on sqlfiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b8f66/14)

The problem is that logic operators are not short-circuited in SQL, so the optimizer treats `CONVERT(date, @query)` as something that it can pre-compute to speed up the query. By expanding the condition to a `CASE` that depends entirely on `@query` you can eliminate the execution of the `CONVERT` branch when `ISDATE(@query)` returns "false".

Comment: it gives me the same error if `@query` is not in form of a date

Comment: @KaranJ.S. You may want to edit the question and specify what you pass as `@query` then.

Comment: @KaranJ.S. It does not look like the conversion error is coming from an attempt on `@query`. Are you sure that all `dateofbirth` values are convertable to `date`? I.e. does this succeed `select convert(date,dateofbirth) from table`?

Comment: yes `select convert(date,dateofbirth) from table` succeeded and returned all the rows

Comment: @KaranJ.S. Please take a look at the edit, it should work now.

Comment: I found that a case statement in the select "when isdate(field)=1" does not resolve the conversion error, but "where isdate(field)=1" does work.  You can solve the problem on a specific-offending record either way, but when the entire query runs, apparently the convert function pre-computes as noted above.